# Javascript/Rails Cookie not saving on safari but works on chrome

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, firefox, cookies, safari

I am developing a rails app (I am a student) and I am trying to make a cookie that stores the users location which is found through the javascript geo location api. However, the cookie works perfectly in chrome but not safari or Firefox. I looked in the inspector and the cookie was there for chrome but not the other two. The code for the cookie is below. The rest of the code is written in ruby. The point of the cookie is so that I can get the users recent location in the controller.

```
<%if @lat_lng.nil? %>

<script>
 getGeoLocation();

function getGeoLocation() {
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(setGeoCookie);
}

 function setGeoCookie(position) {
   var expiration = new Date();
   expiration.setDate(expiration.getDate()+1);
   var cookie_val = position.coords.latitude + "|" + position.coords.longitude;
   document.cookie = "lat_lng=" + escape(cookie_val); expires= 'expiration.toGMTString()';
}
</script>
<% end %>
```

The cookie is defined in my applications controller: 
`@lat_lng = cookies[:lat_lng]`

I really appreciate any help that is possible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are setting the cookie, it should be in the following format:

```
document.cookie = "some=value; expires=Mon, 1 Jan 2000 12:59:59 GMT";
```

In your case, you are simply defining a variable in javascript. Try changing it to:

```
document.cookie = "lat_lng=" + escape(cookie_val) + "; expires=" + expiration.toGMTString();
```

PS. However, the `expires` part is optional and should work without it just fine. Maybe, Safari and FF require it for security reasons? Try googling that.